# How to center this flip card example?

Tags: html, css

I've tried a lot of things, and searched around a lot to find examples on here and on sites, for example `https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/` but I am not having any luck.

I found a fiddle where a guy has created a flip card div, so I thought cool let me try that on my site.  Source: http://jsfiddle.net/uxable/YHeKX/

Here is what my HTML looks like:

```
<section id="test" class="section">

        <div class="row" id="top-section">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Our Pics</h1>
                <p>Check it out!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="flip"> 
                        <div class="card"> 
                        <div class="face front">Front</div> 
                        <div class="face back">Back</div> 
                    </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="flip"> 
                        <div class="card"> 
                        <div class="face front">Front</div> 
                        <div class="face back">Back</div> 
                    </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="flip"> 
                        <div class="card"> 
                        <div class="face front">Front</div> 
                        <div class="face back">Back</div> 
                    </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  -ms-perspective: 800;
  -moz-perspective: 800;
  -o-perspective: 800;
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 50px auto;

}
.flip .card.flipped {
  transform:rotatex(180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotatex(180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotatex(180deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotatex(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform:rotatex(180deg); /* Opera */
}
.flip .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.flip .card .face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 3em;
  backface-visibility: hidden;  /* W3C */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari & Chrome */
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Firefox */
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Opera */

}
.flip .card .front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;

}
.flip .card .back {
    background: blue;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;

  transform:rotatex(-180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotatex(-180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotatex(-180deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotatex(-180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform:rotatex(-180deg); /* Opera */

}
```

The issue is that if I put a paragraph of text on the card, I am not able to keep it centered.  It stays at the top.  How can I center this without too much pain?

Comment: The example you provided looks fine... can you provide another example showing the problem you're having and explain it a little better if needed?

Comment: Hi Shomz.  Thank you and sure.  Is a screenshot fine?  `http://i.imgur.com/KmOlgQY.png`  I am having a very difficult time centering the text vertically inside the div.  If I use line-height, it bleeds out of the div :(

Comment: Ah, I see now, this is about vertically centering texts... I'll write you an answer using absolute positioning.

Comment: Thank you.  I am trying to figure out how to keep the text inside the div without having it go outside the boundary.

Comment: You're welcome. But what will you do if the text cannot fit the container?

Comment: Oh Lord.  I did not think about that.  I have been taking one problem at a time :(  This is what it looks like with really long text: `http://i.imgur.com/c8Ll9go.jpg`

Comment: For this example, due to its complexity, you might have to think about the full picture because if you fix the vertical centering, it might behave differently when you add a multiline text, change font size, etc... You need to decide things like whether the text builds the cards (so the card sizes are flexible) or the other way round, etc.

Comment: okay.  I think I'm going to rework the whole scheme then, so that the text determines the size.  If I make 2 divs, where one is the inner div, and set the inner div to have 100% height of the text, would that work?  Thanks.

Comment: If the text determines the size, the easiest way is just to add vertical padding to the text element.

Comment: ah okay.  going to give that a shot.

Comment: Did my answer not solve your problem?

Comment: I think I'm going to keep height as a number, so I can have uniform height.  Unless I can do height: auto on the row itself, but not sure how I can get it to work.

Comment: Do you want the flip card's height to grow with expanded content?

Comment: I think its OK.  Thanks for your example, I am using it as a table.  I added margin left and right as auto.  Now it is always centered.  So much to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As bad as tables are, they are an easy way to vertically center stuff. See updated fiddle with table to contain multi-line text that is vertically centered inside the flip card:

http://jsfiddle.net/6nhczmnx/

```js
/* card flip */
$(".flip").hover(function(){
  $(this).find(".card").toggleClass("flipped");
  return false;
});
```

```css
body {
 background: #ccc;   
}
.flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  -ms-perspective: 800;
  -moz-perspective: 800;
  -o-perspective: 800;
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 50px auto;
}
.flip .card.flipped {
  transform:rotatey(-180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Opera */
}
.flip .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.flip .card .face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  backface-visibility: hidden;  /* W3C */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari & Chrome */
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Firefox */
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Opera */

}
.flip .card .front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.flip .card .back {
    background: blue;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    
  transform:rotatey(-180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Opera */

}

/* Additional new CSS added below */
.flip .card .face {
  overflow: auto;
}
.flip .card .face table {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip"> 
  <div class="card"> 
      <div class="face front">
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <td><h3>Scrollable Text</h3>
                    Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text</td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </div> 
    <div class="face back">
      <table>
          <tr>
              <td align="left"><p style="text-align:center;">V-centred if contained</p>
               Back text Back text Back text Back text Back text</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I gave you an upvote, but why don't you center the back text as well?

Comment: No real reason to do the back as just need to replace back contents with a table also. However, I've updated the code to include the back now and extra CSS to handle any overflow issues to have a scroll bar.

Comment: Also commented at the end of the CSS styles, what I added additionally to OP to make this work

Comment: The scrollable text on the front face is kinda useless in this case as the hover function forces flip to the back face so you could have overflowed contents scrolling on the back face. As for the front, you need to decide how you want to handle it. Either show ellipsis at the end to show text was cut off or perhaps some javascript to do a transform and resize contents to fit...?